# Border-radius disappears with overflow rule

Tags: css, layout, ionic-framework

I have an issue with using the `overflow:visible;` rule on the Ionic Framework avatar `ion-item`. I would like to create a chat bubble with the user image next to it. I have succeeded in getting the image to overflow out of its parent but the result is the border-radius I have set on the `ion-item` disappears.Without the border radius the border appearscorrectly.

Here's what I'm getting.
[image: Here's what I'm getting]

And what I'm hoping to achieve.

[image: The expected result]

Here's my CSS

```
.item-content,.item, p  {
     overflow: visible;

}

.item-avatar {
    margin-left:15%;
    max-width: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top:10px; 

}

 .item-avatar .item-content > img:first-child,   .item-avatar-left {
    left:-50px;
     overflow: hidden;

}
```

Here is my view template..

```
<ion-view view-title="Chats">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}">
        <img class = "avatar" ng-src="{{chat.face}}">
        <h2>{{chat.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{chat.lastText}}</p>
         <p>{{chat.id}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(chat)">
          Delete
        </ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: A working sample will be much of a help to show exactly the problem. You can use jsfiddle for that or snippets

Comment: If a child div has a background color and is set to be the full width and height of a parent with a border radius, then it will clip the corners like that

Comment: @jtmingus that was the solution, I did a quick check by setting the same border radius on the child elements and voila..post as answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the child element has a background color and is set to the full width and height of the parent element, then the corners will be cut off.

Most likely, your child element doesn't need a background color, so removing it will solve your problem. On the off chance that it does need a background color, then just inherit the border radius from the parent element.

```
.item-avatar-child {
  border-radius: inherit;
}
```